# PHP to make vars and values part of array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach

I currently have this function to search and replace in a text file.

```
// Input
$ect = array('Visssa', 'Lisssa', 'her');

// Placeholders in the file
$put =  array('lname', 'fname', 'hisher');


// Replace the placeholders
$oput = str_replace($put, $ct, 'tmpfile.txt');
```

This is not the full program but the idea is replace the values found in tmpfile.txt with the ones found in the $etc array.  And it works flawlessly.

But, what I need to do is get all passed vars (get/post) and then make the arrays so that the var is the value to replace and the value is the value to replace it with.

So, if I sent the url http://xyz.com/?lname=tom&ogre=yes

All instances of lname in the file would be replaces with tom and all instances of ogre would be replaced with yes.

So somehow it just gets any/all variables passed in get/post and then the arrays showed above would cause the var to be replaced by the value in the file.

Comment: foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
   echo 'Key = ' . $key . '<br />';
   echo 'Value= ' . $value;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
    $etc = array_keys($_GET);
    array_walk($etc,"addBraces");
    $put = array_values($_GET);
    $oput = str_replace($etc, $put, 'tmpfile.txt'); 

    function addBraces(&$item)
    {
        $item = "{".$item."}";
    }
```

And of course, all the regular "always santize/escape your data" etc...

Comment: This did not seem to replace the variables.  Of course I tried with $_REQUEST and not $_GET.

Comment: Got this method to work now changed last line to:
$oput = str_replace($etc, $put, 'tmpfile.txt');

Comment: But, same question as below - if I want to automatically enclose each var_key in {} to make it so it only replaces enclosed {values} in the text file...  How?

?lname=hello will replace all instances of lname in the text file, but how can it automatically enclose it so it would replace all instances of {lname} with hello but leave an un{enclosed} lname alone?

Comment: @Chris: you need to add braces `{}` to the etc array and use it. I have updated the answer to reflect it

Answer (score 0):

parse_str() will be perfect for this

```
function addreplacetokens(&$input)
{
  $input = '{' . $input . '}';
}

$string = 'word {lname} word {fname} word {hisher} word';
$filter = array('lname','fname','hisher');
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$replacements);
foreach($replacements as $key => $value)
  if(in_array($key,$filter) == false)
    unset($replacements[$key]);
// this next block can be removed if you don't want a default
foreach($filter as $key)
  if(array_key_exists($key,$replacements) == false)
    $replacements[$key] = ''; // change this!
// copy the array so the keys can be filtered
$replacements_keys = array_keys($replacements);
array_walk($replacements_keys,'addreplacetokens');
$string = str_replace($replacements_keys,$replacements,$string);
echo $string;
```

so that *?lname=hello* will output

> word hello word word word

the next issue, is do you need to deal with word boundaries or not?

Comment: What you might want to do is filter $replacements on your placeholder values though after it's been parsed from the Query string to isolate only the replacements you want.

Comment: see my revised code, it has an array of your filters, so that other query string parameters can be ignored.

Comment: The first method worked, I understand the filter so that only the wanted text is replaced...  Is there a way to instead make it simply look for a "mark" of sorts.

so ?lname=hello

doesn't replace all instances of lname but of {lname} for example.  This way, only actual replaceable variables marked with {variable} would be replaced so if someone put ?the=cat all the instances of the are not replaced unless in the textfile it is marked {the}?

The idea is not to have to edit the php file ever but only the text files.  So the filter method will not achieve that but a "mark"  would.

Comment: Reveiw my edit, I've changed it to a token system where "{lname}" is the token instead of just "lname".